# I want to add metadata to the Solana token on cli

Tags: spl-token, solana-cli, cli, phantom-wallet

I have created a token in solana using the cli but now I'm unable to add metadata can someone please help me.

https://solscan.io/token/Gy5oaTpM6tkc9aj4BZkjMXHaWm2U16CsfBtL4jBMKztX

Answer (score 3):

Token metadata on Solana is normally all handled via the [Metaplex Metadata](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/overview) standard. For both fungible (regular SPL tokens) and non-fungible tokens (NFTs).

So unfortunately, you cannot use the regular Solana CLI to add the token metadata.

Answer (score 1):

We can use  [@metaplex-foundation/js](https://www.quicknode.com/guides/solana-development/spl-tokens/how-to-create-a-fungible-spl-token-with-the-new-metaplex-token-standard/).
Please check the guide.

- You have to use **createCreateMetadataAccountV3Instruction** instead of using **createCreateMetadataAccountV2Instruction** .

Answer (score 0):

Install the Solana Command Line Interface (CLI) first. You can follow the [installation steps](https://docs.solana.com/cli/install-solana-cli-tools) in the Solana manual if you don't already have it installed.

Once the Solana CLI is set up, adhere to these instructions to add metadata to your token:

1. Create the metadata file
2. Upload the metadata file to a web server
3. Update the token with metadata

You can produce a JSON-formatted metadata file containing information about your token. The metadata file should contain details on your token's name, symbol, image, and other characteristics. The metadata file can be created with a text editor and saved with the.json extension.

**Here Metadata example**

```
{
  "name": "My Token",
  "symbol": "MT",
  "uri": "https://example.com/token/1",
  "seller_fee_basis_points": 500,
  "fee_recipient": "YOUR_SOLANA_ADDRESS",
  "seller_fee_collection_address": "YOUR_SOLANA_ADDRESS",
  "image": "https://example.com/token/1/image",
  "seller_fee_burn_address": null,
  "properties": {
    "files": [
      {
        "uri": "https://example.com/token/1/file",
        "type": "text/plain"
      }
    ],
    "category": "digital",
    "creators": [
      {
        "address": "YOUR_SOLANA_ADDRESS",
        "share": 100
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I have made everything but don't know where to upload since the git repo has been archived

Comment: I have made everything just want some guidance to add metadata from cli or any other way, the repo has been archived

Comment: Repo update method no more exists. You have to install metaplex and from your terminal run metaplex update_metadata \
  --env mainnet-beta \
  --keypair /path/to/your/wallet.json \
  --mint <Token Mint Address> \
  --uri <New Metadata URL>. Everything is well documented